# Trying to get to api

Tags: java, api, rest

I try to get to this api : https://www.football-data.org/. I have key and token name. From Postman I can get to this api by "Api Key" autorization with name : X-Auth-Token and token XXXX. But how can I do this from java with rest template ? How should i put my headers to this url:

```
  public List<FootballDto> getFootballs() {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add(tokenName,token);
        FootballDto[] footballResponse = restTemplate.getForObject(
                "https://api.football-data.org/v2/competitions/SA/scorers", FootballDto[].class
        );
    }
```

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RestTemplate `getForObject()` method doesn't support setting headers. The solution is to use the `exchange()` method. So instead of `restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class, param)` (which has no headers), use:

```
 HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
 headers.set("Header-1", "value-1");
 headers.set("Header-2", "value-2");
 ...

 HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);

 ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class, param);
```

Finally, use `response.getBody()` to get your result.